# Will the trajectory of a body moving straight towards a rotating BH differ if space just rotates around or if space spiralls into the BH?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, astrophysics, frame-dragging

Will the trajectory of a body moving straight towards a rotating BH differ if space just rotates around or if space spiralls into the BH? Can this difference be clearly measured? Also as a very dense body can give a high angular moment to space around it as in the case of a rotating black hole in contrast with a body of less density as our Sun that gives a very low angular momentum to space to produce frame-dragging effect does it mean that space has its own density equivalent which is more close to very dense objects instead less dense astrophysical objects?

Answer (score 1):

> Krešimir Bradvica asked: *"Will the trajectory of a body moving straight towards a rotating BH differ if space just rotates around or if space spiralls into the BH?"*

The description of space spiraling into the black hole corresponds to radial attraction plus angular frame dragging (in that case the ZAMO needs to be blast its rocket in the radial direction in order to stay at a fixed radial coordinate), while talking about space only rotating around the black hole without spiraling in would be the equivalent of no radial attraction, so that path would differ from the path of a test particle that is also radially attracted.

If you use the Gullstrand Painlevé equivalent for spinning black holes known as the Doran metric, the path is not a spiral though since in that coordinates the frame dragging of a free falling test particle gets flattened out:

> [Hamilton & Lisle](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060) wrote: *"One might have anticipated that the river would spiral into the black hole like a whirlpool, but that is not the case. Rather, the river velocity has no azimuthal component at all. Instead of a spiral, the river possesses, besides a velocity at each point, a rotation, or twist, at each point."*

In Boyer Lindquist coordinates the free faller which flows with the so called river of space does spiral in though, but you can't plot the crossing of the horizon in that coordinates since the test particle gets stuck at the horizon corotating until the end of eternity in terms of the bookkeeper's coordinate time.

> Krešimir Bradvica asked: *"Does it mean that space has its own density equivalent which is more close to very dense objects instead less dense astrophysical objects?"*

Not from the relativistic perspective, where the Kerr metric is a vacuum solution where the density outside the black hole is 0, only if the black hole is also charged you have an energy density outside that comes from the electromagnetic field, see the energy tensor for the [Kerr Newman metric](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/18.html#9).